# Load script and styles using an array of resources

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I want to simplify the scripts and the stylesheet loading in my wordpress plugin. I have this code style now, but I want to implement a best solution, this to encache the function readbility. Is there any way to enqueque the scripts and styles with a foreach? I was thinking to implement a check to verify if the script or style is already enqueued and then if not, load it.

Here is the code.

```php
// plugin class method
  public function init() : void
  {

    if( !wp_script_is( 'popper-js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'popper' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/popper.min.js', ['jquery'] );
    }

    if( !wp_script_is( 'bootstrap-js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['jquery'] );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'bootstrap-css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    }

    if( !wp_script_is( 'parallax-js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'parallax' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/universal-parallax.min.js' );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'parallax-css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'parallax-css' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/css/universal-parallax.min.css' );
    }

    if( !wp_script_is( 'swiper-js' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/swiper.min.js' );
    }

    if( !wp_style_is( 'swiper-css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper-css' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/css/swiper.min.css' );
    }
  }
```

I want to avoid to call the `wp_style_is` or `wp_script_is` and the related `wp_enqueue_` functions. my pseudo code solution is this, but any suggestion will be appreciated:

```
  public function init() : void
  {
    // check if the file has the -js or -css name
    //$resources = [ 'swiper-css', 'swiper-js' ];
    foreach( $resouces as $res ){
      if( !wp_script_is(  , 'enqueued' ) || !wp_style_is( 'swiper-css' , 'enqueued' ) ){
        wp_enqueue_style( $res.'-css' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/css/'.$res.'.min.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script( $res.'-js' , PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/'.$res.'.min.js' );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the above code trying to do by condiitonally enquing those scripts? It's very unusual, can you add some context?

Comment: @TomJNowell The scripts and styles are the dependencies of my plugin for the front end. I want to load them if the user didn't have them loaded in his custom theme.

Comment: There's no guarantee that's what those scripts will be loaded as, or that they'll be a version that works, so you should just enqueue directly, and use any that core provide preferentially. A theme might not even enqueue them, and use a webpack bundle with all their librarys bundled together and minified. There's also nothing in that class method that requires it to be inside a class. It could be replaced with a simple function that takes a `$plugin_dir` parameter. Otherwise there's no array version of the enqueue scripts/styles API, but this can be simplified using some basic PHP

Comment: Just wrap the enqueue functions in a new function that checks `wp_script_is`, then call that, then you can just loop over an array calling your new function